# what will network-manager-config-connectivity-debian do?

Tags: debian, networking, networkmanager

I am on Debian #buster and saw this new package `network-manager-config-connectivity-debian` . While I use `ping some FQDN`to access connectivity, how is this package supposed to help. I am using ifupdown instead of network-manager as it has proved to be far more reliable for me than network-manager ever was. The fact that I could connect or disconnect to the network with a single command is a side benefit.

I did apt-file list network-manager-config-connectivity-debian to see what it will say and it says -

```
[$] apt-file list network-manager-config-connectivity-debian                                                                       
network-manager-config-connectivity-debian: /usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-debian.conf
network-manager-config-connectivity-debian: /usr/share/doc/network-manager-config-connectivity-debian/changelog.Debian.gz
network-manager-config-connectivity-debian: /usr/share/doc/network-manager-config-connectivity-debian/changelog.gz
network-manager-config-connectivity-debian: /usr/share/doc/network-manager-config-connectivity-debian/copyright
```

Looking forward to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It installs a single configuration snippet that enables connectivity checking. See the `connectivity` section in `man NetworkManager.conf`.

It tells NetworkManager to periodically HTTP get a certain URL to decide whether internet is reachable. A major use is to detect captive portals, like in a hotel.

Other applications may then make use of that information. Like gnome-shell may decide to show the login for captive portals and a question mark in the network icon, to signal limited connectivity.

Comment: Specifically it installs `/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-debian.conf` where you can see that it will attempt to contact `http://network-test.debian.org/nm` to check whether you are online or not.